# Using CombinePDF/Prawn/Paperclip all in one method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5, prawn

So I'm not sure if this is a proper question for StackOverflow but with no one else to turn to I figured I'd try here.

Now, the below code **works** for it's intended purpose. However, I would consider myself a novice with Rails without the experience to foresee any consequences that might arise in the future as my application scales.

So the idea is that when the user clicks on a 'Generate PDF' button,  **Prawn** will generate the custom PDF, **CombinePDF** will combine this and PDF's from associated sources, then the final PDF will be saved to the Rails.root directory (only because I don't know how to pass a save location to CombinePDF and have searched everywhere), then **Paperclip** will attach it to its appropriate model, then the original PDF generated in Rails.root will be deleted to clean up the directory.

**Orders `show` action in `Orders Controller`**

```
def show
  @orders = Order.find(params[:id])
  @properties = Property.find(@orders.property.id)
  @deeds = Deed.where(property_id: @properties, order_id: @orders).all
  @mortgages = Mortgage.where(property_id: @properties, order_id: @orders).all
  @attached_assets = AttachedAsset.where(property_id: @properties, order_id: @orders).all
  @owners = Owner.where(property_id: @properties, order_id: @orders).all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      order_pdf = OrderPdf.new(@orders, @properties, @deeds, @mortgages, @attached_assets).render
      combine_order_pdf = CombinePDF.new
      combine_order_pdf << CombinePDF.parse(order_pdf)
      if @deeds.any?
        @deeds.each do |deed|
          combine_order_pdf << CombinePDF.load(deed.document.path)
        end
      end
      if @mortgages.any?
        @mortgages.each do |mtg|
          combine_order_pdf << CombinePDF.load(mtg.document.path)
        end
      end
      if @attached_assets.any?
        @attached_assets.each do |assets|
          combine_order_pdf << CombinePDF.load(assets.asset.path)
        end
      end
      combine_order_pdf.save "order_#{@orders.order_number}.pdf"
      paperclip_pdf = File.open("order_#{@orders.order_number}.pdf")
      @orders.document = paperclip_pdf
      @orders.save
      File.delete("order_#{@orders.order_number}.pdf")
      redirect_to property_order_path(@properties, @orders)
      flash[:success] = "PDF Generated Successfully. Please scroll down."
    end
  end
end
```

**Generate PDF button in `Orders show view`**

```
<%= link_to fa_icon("files-o"), order_path(@orders, format: "pdf"), class: "m-xs btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-outline" %>
```

**To be clear:** This code does *work*, but what I'm **asking** is:

- Is all this logic appropriate in a controller function or is there a better place for it?
- Will this process bottleneck my application?
- Is there a better way to save directly to Paperclip after CombinePDF/Prawn do their thing?
- Can I pass a save location to CombinePDF so its not in Rails.root?
- Is storing Paperclip attachments in Rails.root/public the only way to have them able to be accessed/displayed on an **intranet** Rails app?
- Is there anything I'm not seeing about this method that may put my application at risk for either performance, security, or stability?

Again, I understand if this isn't an appropriate question(s) but I have no one else to ask so if it is then let me know and I'll take it down. I guess to satisfy the 'Answerable' criteria for this question would be anyone who could tell me the rails way of doing this and why and/or answering the above questions. Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is all this logic appropriate in a controller function or is there a better place for it?**

Yes, ideally your action should be of 7-8 lines and remaining piece can either become another action or go inside a module which you can place in concerns folder. ex: you can take out your pdf logic and write another method inside `concerns` folder with file name `orders_related.rb`

```
module OrdersRelated
              def self.parsing_pdf(orders, properties, deeds, mortgages, attached_assets)
                  order_pdf = OrderPdf.new(orders, properties, deeds, mortgages, attached_assets).render
                  .
                  .
                  @orders.document = paperclip_pdf
                  @orders.save
                  File.delete("order_#{@orders.order_number}.pdf")
                  redirect_to property_order_path(@properties, @orders)
        end
end
```

**Will this process bottleneck my application?**

Yes, this kind of processing should alway happen in the background. Won't go into the details of which you should be using as it depends upon your requirements.

**Is storing Paperclip attachments in Rails.root/public the only way to have them able to be accessed/displayed on an intranet Rails app?**

No, You should be using a storage service like `s3 bucket` for to keep your files. there are many advantages of doing it which again is out of scope of this question.

**Is there anything I'm not seeing about this method that may put my application at risk for either performance, security, or stability?**

Yes, your method clearly needs lot of refactoring I can suggest few

- Remove `.all` from all query it is not required
- add `index` to these columns (property, order) in all table
- Never save important files to your public directory(use third party storage service)

p.s: I intentionally left two questions as I don't have much experience with CombinePdf.

Comment: I apologize in the delay for responding but thank you for your reply! I like the suggestion about moving the pdf logic into its own module, that seems smart. Would you be willing to chat sometime so that I can pick your brain about some of your other answers as I've tried similar storage/query options but they didn't seem to work out for my purposes so maybe I'm misunderstanding them. I'd create a chat but I don't have permissions yet. If not then thank you for your suggestions and I'll try to figure it out!

Comment: @cdouble.bhuck I guess our time zone are different but if you want to discuss something now then I am available for a quick chat. Otherwise you can always update your question and I shall try to answer if I could.

Comment: Sure I am available now if you still are! Thanks

Comment: How do we start a chat?

Comment: here is the link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150241/room-for-abhinay-and-cdouble-bhuck